# Repair lifted ground pad on power amp

Tags: pcb, audio, repair

I'm repairing a 250W bass power amp board and one of the problems is that the pads for two ground wires have lifted off the board. It looks like it has had something of a bodge repair done before and there doesn't seem to be much in the way of pad left.

For a tiny pad connecting to a component I can see that repair would not be too difficult, but this seems a bit more tricky given the higher power, bigger pads and the chunky wires. I wondered what the best approach might be to fix this. I thought about a terminal connector, but then that needs to be soldered into place, so perhaps something mechanically attached to the board and then connected to the rest of the ground trace, or am I over-complicating things?

Here be pics:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could carefully scrape away the solder mask on the trace going to the pad and solder the wire to that.

Comment: You're in luck here, because it looks like your lifted pad is connected directly to some other pads just to the left of it.

Comment: Good suggestions - is there any significant mechanical disadvantage to soldering to the underside of the board?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do this:

- Unsolder everything and clean up all old solder.
- Get a piece of copper foil tape, remove the adhesive with acetone, and cut it to size.
- Put a small amount of solder (solder paste would work even better, but unless you do your own SMD work you probably wouldn't have any around, and it's fairly expensive stuff), and with the heaviest-duty soldering iron you have work over the top of the tape so the solder "filling" melts and attaches it to the old pads.

  - Drill holes and re-attach the old wires.
  - Post pictures if you succeed :)